# Magento list categories via position and html output by number of sub-categories

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I am trying to do two things with the following code.
1) Currently the output is sorting the categories based on category ID, but I would like it to match the backend position structure.
2) I would like to be able to change the html output depending on the number of direct children the category has, so I can output categories that have no direct children with different css styling.

The code I have thus far is

```
<?php 
$parentCategoryId = 486;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();
?> 
<?php 
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
    echo '<ul><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
    $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
    foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
    {
          $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
          if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
              echo '<li class="sub_cat1"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
              $sub_sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
              $sub_sub_subcats = $sub_sub_cat->getChildren();
              foreach(explode(',',$sub_sub_subcats) as $sub_sub_subCatid)
          {
                $_sub_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_sub_subCatid);
                if($_sub_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                    echo '<li class="sub_cat2"><a href="'.$_sub_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
                    $sub_sub_sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_sub_subCatid);
              $sub_sub_sub_subcats = $sub_sub_sub_cat->getChildren();
              foreach(explode(',',$sub_sub_sub_subcats) as $sub_sub_sub_subCatid)
              {
                $_sub_sub_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_sub_sub_subCatid);
                if($_sub_sub_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                    echo '<li class="sub_cat3"><a href="'.$_sub_sub_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_sub_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_sub_sub_category->getName().'</a></li>';
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
           }
     }
     echo '</ul>';
  }
}
?>
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
        <?php 
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(486);
        $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $children->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $category->getId())
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories if you want
                ->addAttributeToSort('position');//sort by position

        foreach ($children as $sub_subCatid){
            echo $sub_subCatid->getName();
            $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
            $children->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $sub_subCatid->getId())
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories if you want
                ->addAttributeToSort('position');//sort by position
            //repeat the loop   foreach ($children as $sub_subCatid){ //repeat the loop }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Could you tell me how I would inject the link and html tags  into this code?  As it is, it only outputs the names with no mark up.

Thank you very much!